# Independent random variables and survival function

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution, hazard

I just started taking survival analysis class and I'm stumped on this question.

Let $T_{1},T_{2},...T_{n}$ independent continuous non-negative random
variables with survival function $S(t)$

Show that $S(t)$ ~ $U(0, 1)$.

Find the distribution of $-log S(t)$

Answer (score 1):

They meant: show that S(T_i) ~ U([0,1]). This is a consequence of the fact that if random variable X has distribution function F(x) then F(X) ~ U([0,1]).